# Python script to count pixel values fails on a less-than/greater-than comparison

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, operators, truthiness

I wrote a short script to count the pixel values in an image:

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

imn = (sys.argv[1])
a = cv2.imread(imn, 0)
b = cv2.imread(imn, 1)
c = cv2.GaussianBlur(cv2.imread(imn, 0), (7,7), 2)

def NC(img):
    y = img.reshape(1, -1)
    numA = (y < 127.5).sum()
    numB = (y > 127.5).sum()
    return ({'less': numA, 'greater': numB})

aa = NC(a)
bb = NC(b)
cc = NC(c)
print "File:  {}".format(imn.split('/')[-1])
print "Image: {} - Set: {}".format('A', aa)
print "Image: {} - Set: {}".format('B', bb)
print "Image: {} - Set: {}".format('C', cc)
```

And it works perfectly:

```
File:  ObamaBidenSituationRoom.jpg
Image: A - Set: {'greater': 480558, 'less': 611282}
Image: B - Set: {'greater': 1441948, 'less': 1833572}
Image: C - Set: {'greater': 471559, 'less': 620281}
```

But when I tried to expand it:

```
def NC(img):
    y = img.reshape(1, -1)

    numA = (00.99 < y < 85.00).sum()
    numB = (85.00 < y < 170.0).sum()
    numC = (170.0 < y < 256.0).sum()

    return ({'low': numA, 'middle': numB, 'high': numC})
```

It gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bins--02.py", line 25, in <module>
    aa = NC(a)
  File "Bins--02.py", line 17, in NC
    numA = (00.99 < y < 85.00).sum()
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I got this image a while ago, but that was with a matplotlib library that I ended up not using. Why is it coming up here? Am I bounding that greater-than/less-than signs wrong? I tried to fix it

`numA = (00.99 < y).sum() and (y < 85.00).sum()`

But that just gave me random super high values.

***UPDATE - Oct20***

So, I changed it:

```
def NC(img):
    x = img.reshape(1, -1)


    numA = x[np.where((00.99 < x) & (x < 85.00))].sum()
    numB = x[np.where((85.00 < x) & (x < 170.0))].sum()
    numC = x[np.where((170.0 < x) & (x < 256.0))].sum()
    numD = x.shape

    return ({'total': numD, 'low': numA, 'middle': numB, 'high': numC})
```

And now it works, but there's a problem: the pixel counts don't match up.

```
Image:  lenna.png
Image:  A Set:{'high': 8367459, 'middle': 20278460, 'total': (1, 262144), 'low': 3455619}
Image:  B Set:{'high': 45250935, 'middle': 43098232, 'total': (1, 786432), 'low': 11609051}
Image:  C Set:{'high': 8216989, 'middle': 20633144, 'total': (1, 262144), 'low': 3531090}
```

The measurements are pixels, there can't be more than the total. Where am I getting 2 million from?

For example, I ran it on a 100x100 image of a blue circle:

```
Image:  lightblue.png
Image:  A Set:{'high': 0, 'middle': 1035999, 'total': (1, 10000), 'low': 0}
Image:  B Set:{'high': 1758789, 'middle': 1212681, 'total': (1, 30000), 'low': 417612}
Image:  C Set:{'high': 0, 'middle': 1014135, 'total': (1, 10000), 'low': 31801}
```

and it's completely wrong.

***Edit Two***

I just ran it on a test array:

```
i = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]])

def NC(img):
    x = img.reshape(1, -1)
    numA = x[np.where((00.99 < x) & (x < 85.00))].sum()
    numB = x[np.where((85.00 < x) & (x < 170.0))].sum()
    numC = x[np.where((170.0 < x) & (x < 256.0))].sum()
    numD = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1])
    return ({'total': numD, 'low': numA, 'middle': numB, 'high': numC})

aa = NC(i)
bb = NC(i)
cc = NC(i)

print "Image:  {} Set:{}".format('A', aa)
print "Image:  {} Set:{}".format('B', bb)
print "Image:  {} Set:{}".format('C', cc)
```

And it's entirely broken:

```
Image:  A Set:{'high': 1600, 'middle': 0, 'total': 24, 'low': 32}
Image:  B Set:{'high': 1600, 'middle': 0, 'total': 24, 'low': 32}
Image:  C Set:{'high': 1600, 'middle': 0, 'total': 24, 'low': 32}
```

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your approach.

When you do

```
(y < 85.00).sum()
```

You're actually summing over the truth condition. So you end up counting where the condition evaluates to `True`. You can easily see it with a quick example:

```
In [6]: x = np.arange(10)

In [7]: x
Out[7]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [8]: x < 4
Out[8]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [9]: (x < 4).sum()
Out[9]: 4
```

Now if you want to get the indices where the condition is satisfied, you can use `np.where`

```
In [10]: np.where(x < 4)
Out[10]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3]),)
```

And use them for your sum

```
In [11]: x[np.where(x < 4)].sum()
Out[11]: 6
```

The other issue comes from using the compact notation for the range which is easily solved splitting it in two with `&` or `np.logical_and()`

```
In [12]: x[np.where((2 < x) & (x < 6))].sum()
Out[12]: 12
```

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I still have a problem: The number of pixels keeps fluctuating wildly.

Comment: Wait, maybe I didn't really understand what are you trying to do. Do you want to count the number of array elements that match your condition or do you want to sum over their content? If you want the first the whole `np.where` stuff doesn't apply. You should get the right result just doing `((00.99 < x) & (x < 85.00)).sum()`

Comment: I updated my post, but the basic is this: if I have array: ([1, 1], [2, 2], [200, 200]) I want to get the number of images between the three margins I set.

Comment: Pardon, then my fault I misread your question, you should be able to fix it like I said in my previous comment.